# Как получить информацию об ID сокета на стороне клиента при событии on('disconnect')

Tags: javascript, сокет, socket.io

Использую библиотеку socket.io

Как получить информацию об ID сокета на стороне клиента при событии on('disconnect')

Пробовал вот так, не получилось:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        let socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000')

        socket.on('connect', function()
        {
            alert(socket.id + ': is connected.')
        })

        socket.on('disconnect', function()
        {
            alert(socket.id + ': is disconnected.')
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: А что значит не получилось?

Comment: при console.log(socket.id) выдаёт undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете сохранить id в переменную.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    let socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000')
    let socketId;  
    socket.on('connect', function()
    {
        alert(socket.id + ': is connected.')
        socketId = socket.id;
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', function()
    {
        alert(socketId + ': is disconnected.')
    })
})
```